# MVVM/WPF app RadGridView binding to EntityFrameworkDataSource

Tags: wpf, mvvm, telerik, entity-framework-6, radgridview

I am trying to bind a RadGridView to an EntityFrameworkDataSource so I can avoid writing the paging/filtering myself but I can't get it to work.  I have checked Telerik's example but it doesn't seem to work either.  Using WPF w/ EF 6

My context:

```
public class TIMSContext : DbContext
{
    public TIMSContext()
        : base("name=TIMSContext") { }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //map models here...
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query<T>()
    {
        return this.Set(typeof(T)).AsQueryable() as IQueryable<T>;
    }

}
```

My XAML:

```
     <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="RadGridView1"
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             AlternateRowBackground="CornflowerBlue"
                             AlternationCount="2"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                             CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                             CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
                             CanUserInsertRows="False"
                             GroupRenderMode="Flat"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding ShipmentData}"
                             RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" />

        <telerik:RadDataPager Grid.Row="1"
                              DisplayMode="FirstLastPreviousNextNumeric"
                              PageSize="25"
                              Source="{Binding ShipmentData}" />
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class ShipmentsViewModel :ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly QueryableEntityCollectionView<TIMS.Data.Entities.ASN> shipments;
    private readonly TIMS.Data.TIMSContext ctx;

    public ShipmentsViewModel()
    {
        try
        {
            ctx = new Data.TIMSContext();
            shipments = new QueryableEntityCollectionView<Data.Entities.ASN>(ctx, "ASN");
            //Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TIMS.Data.TIMSContext' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'


            //Also tried this which I saw on some forums...
            //shipments = new QueryableEntityCollectionView<Data.Entities.ASN>( ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext, "ASN"); 
            //Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    #region Properties

    public Object ShipmentData
    {
        get
        {
            return shipments;
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a specific assembly for EF 6.... Need to reference Telerik.Windows.Controls.EntityFramework60.  And must cast the DbContext to an IObjectContextAdapater as in the code above.

Also, you must explicitly define properties in the context for each DbSet and provide the name when you make the function call.  That part is somewhat annoying...